# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}-7&2&-6\\3&-2&3\\6&-2&5\end{bmatrix}

When I was trying to find the eigenvalues for this matrix, I found the following equation:

$λ^3 + 4λ^2 +5λ +2 = 0$

When I used rational root rest, I came up with the following answers: $-2,-1$. But it should 3 roots. When I used online calculator, I found that there will be three roots: $-2, -1$ and $-1$.

Can someone explain me why there are going to be two $-1$ roots but not two $-2$ roots?

Comment: That's just because the polynomial $x^3+4x^2+5x+2$ decomposes into $(x+2)(x+1)(x+1)$, that is $-1$ is the double root.

Answer (score 3):

The root $-1$ has a multiplicity of $2$. You can factor the polynomial into the product of its roots:
$$(\lambda + 2)(\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 1)$$